# MySQL Unknown Column for the Value in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to update an entry in **MySQL from Python** with the following query

```
"""UPDATE reporting_lib set %s=%s+%d WHERE `identifier`=`%s`;"""%
  (str(month_id), str(month_id), value, str(var))
```

When var(ABC-284 in this case) exists in the identifier column, Update is working fine. If the value is not present, then MySQL is throwing

> MySQL Error [1054]: Unknown column 'ABC-284' in 'where clause'

The same when executed **directly from MySQL**, doesn't throw this error. In Where Clause, I'm giving a value rather than a column(ABC-284). How is this being affected?

Already tried with the following methods in vain:

> """UPDATE reporting_lib set %s=%s+%d WHERE identifier=%s;"""%
>         (str(month_id), str(month_id), value, str(var))

and

> """UPDATE reporting_lib set %s=%s+%s WHERE identifier =%s;"""
>
> cursor.execute(sql,(str(month_id),str(month_id),value, str(var)))

EDIT1:
The same Query is working if I change the value of var to just some numbers

> var = 284

Comment: This won't work, because no prepared statement API will let you dynamically specify a column name.  Think about it, if your query actually worked, what would stop someone from changing columns?

Comment: As always, avoid string formatting values in to SQL query strings like the plague. Use placeholders, and if you *must* use dynamic columns, instead of rethinking the problem, whitelist.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I completely agree with you. But this code will be run through a class instance and column name is generated in the previous step. So, we can forget the case of SQL Injection here

Comment: Then you will have to add an additional step which lays out the columns.  AFAIK you cannot choose columns in a prepared statement.